# How do I use Graphql generated JWT to authenticate my rest_framework view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, graphql, jwt

I am using Graphql jwt to generate my token but I am not able to find a way to authenticate my rest_framework view using that token.

Comment: please share code showing what you have tried

Comment: @Jimmar Thanks for asking but I solved it by making my own TokenAuthentication class for rest_framwork views.